# Install older version of tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-10, anaconda

I currently have Tensorflow 1.0.1 installed, and I want to install Tensorflow 0.12.1 (an older version.) I was not able to find a working online solution to install it for Windows 10 using the Anaconda 64-bit distribution and on Python 3.5.3.

How would I be able to install Tensorflow 0.12.1?

Comment: Did you google [install tensorflow windows 0.12.1](https://www.gitbook.com/book/isaacyaf/install-tensorflow-0-12-windows-64bits-ver-cpu/details)?

Comment: Have you tried 'conda install tensorflow=0.12.1' ?

Comment: Yes. I've tried both of them non of them worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

I was able to solve the problem.
If you to use certain version of a package for the a specific application, you can simply use virtualEN. Check out this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5vscPTWKOk).